# How to change the value of a variable from WinDbg cmd line?

Tags: debugging, windbg

There's an extern variable defined in the code, which I need to set to true/false through the debugger (for enhanced debug dumps and stuff). What would be the command to change its value from the cmd line in windbg (equivalent to gdb's `p flag=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it :

`?? <module>!<variable>=<value>`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Edit Memory command **e** to edit a byte:

eb module!variable value

Note that there's also ew, ed, eq, ep, etc.

-scott